# Sectioning bibliography by type (with multiple types per section)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting, subdividing

I would like to distinguish books from articles, manuals, etc. This can be done by using:

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Book References},type=book]
```

or

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Other References},nottype=book,nottype=manual]
```

Multiple 'nottype' can be entered to restrict the types of a certain subsection. But: I would like to 'whitelist' instead of 'backlist' my types, e.g.:

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Articles, Proceedings},type={article,inproceedings}]
```

However, this does not seem to work (using multiple type identifiers does not work either). I checked the manual and could not find how this may work out. Can this be done without using custom extra keys?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

An alternative is to define a `bibfilter`  for the multiple entry types

```
\defbibfilter{papers}{
  type=article or
  type=inproceedings
}
```

and then

```
\printbibliography[filter=papers]
```

Comment: Great! :-) Exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: This does solve the issue at hand. But according to the `biblatex` documentation, type should actually accept a comma separated list as provided by @user26372 in the original question!