# Changing reference title to "Referanser"

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, sharelatex

I am trying to change the header of "References" to "Referanser", but it does not seem to work.

At the start of the code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\graphicspath{ {Bilder/} }
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Referanser.bib}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=140mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Figurliste}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Innholdsfortegnelse}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Referanser}
```

And at the end of the code:

`\printbibliography`

Also, is it possible to separate the references in categories such as "Books", "Articles" and "Web links"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please complete your example in order to make it compilable for us. But keep as minimal as possible. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you should load `babel` with your language option.

Comment: To change the title, try `\printbibliography[title={Referanser}]`, to only display books, `\printbibliography[title={Referanser},type=book]`

Answer (score 1):

Before tweaking all the titles in your document, you should take a look on the `norsk` option of `babel`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex

\begin{filecontents}{Referanser.bib}
    @article{A2012,
        author = {Author, A},
        title = {An interesting paper},
        journal = {Journal},
        year = {2012},
        volume = {2},
        pages = {70--76},
    }
    @article{B2012,
        author = {Buthor, B},
        title = {An also interesting paper},
        journal = {Journal},
        year = {2012},
        volume = {2},
        pages = {77--79},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Referanser.bib}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=140mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cite{A2012}

\cite{B2012}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

---

For your second question. This has been treated a lot on this site here and is also answered in samcarter's comment above.

Comment: Do you know if it´s possible to separate the references in categories as well?

Comment: @Oystein [Sectioning bibliography by type (with multiple types per section)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112874)